# Logging exceptions in C# ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have been doing some revision regarding  ASP.NET MVC applications for an upcoming exam and found the following question:

You maintain an ASP.NET MVC applicaton. Errors are logged to the Trace object. The applicaton
contains the following code. Line numbers are included for reference only:

[image]

[image]

The Load method throws an exception.
For each of the following statements, select Yes if the statement is true. Otherwise, select No.

[image]

All of the answers previously written are: Yes, No, Yes respectively. However, this does not make sense to me. Are the answers correct?

[image]

This is the order that I am interpreting that the answer is placing the events.

1) Number of exceptions incremented.

2) View is Rendered.

When is the exception logged?

According to answer 2, since it is marked as false - **After the view is rendered**

According to answer 3, **Before the number of exceptions is incremented**

Any help with the above contradiction would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/app-domains/how-to-receive-first-chance-exception-notifications)

> The FirstChanceException event of the AppDomain class lets you receive
>   a notification that an exception has been thrown, before the common
>   language runtime has begun searching for exception handlers.

which suggests #1 true #2 true #3 false are the correct answers.

One scenario that fits the answers you've been given implies you are logging to a file and have not set Trace.Autoflush = true or used Trace.Flush(), in which case you wouldn't be seen the exception on your file before the view is rendered or the variable incremented. But the question per se does not imply any of that.